# Is there a way to manipulate rendered text in react component children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a component that highlights text inside it's children recursively.

What I have been able to achieve, is to highlight the text only if it's explicitly provided in the body component, but I can't find a way to change the text of the component's render part.

Let's say I have the following `HighlightText` component:
*(Note, that this is a concept component. The real component is much more complicated)*

```js
const HighlightText = ({highlight, children}) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${regexEscape(highlight)})`, 'gi');
    return React.Children.map(children, child => {
        // Found a text, can highlight
        if (typeof child === 'string') {
            const text = child.trim();
            if (text) {
                return text.split(regex).filter(p => p).map((p, i) =>
                    regex.test(p) ? <mark key={i}>{p}</mark> : <span>{p}</span>;
                );
            }
        }
        
        // If child is a react component, recurse through its children to find more text to highlight
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            if (child.props && child.props.children) {
                return HighlightText({children: child.props.children, highlight});
            }
        }

        // Here I believe, should be another handling that handles the result of the render function to search for more text to highlight...  

        // For any other cases, leave the child as is.
        return child;
    })
}
```

And some component that renders something:

```js
const SomeContent = () => <div>content</div>;
```

Now, I want to use the `HighlightText` component the following way:

```js
ReactDOM.render(

    <HighlightText highlight="e">
        <SomeContent />
        <p>some paragraph</p>
        nude text
    </HighlightText>

,document.body);
```

The resulted DOM of the the above code is:

```html
<div>content</div>
<p><span>som</span><mark>e</mark><span> paragraph</span></p>
<span>nud</span><mark>e</mark><span> t</span><mark>e</mark><span>xt</span>
```

But I expect it to be:

```html
<div><span>cont</span><mark>e</mark><span>nt</span></div>
<p><span>som</span><mark>e</mark><span> paragraph</span></p>
<span>nud</span><mark>e</mark><span> t</span><mark>e</mark><span>xt</span>
```

**Any suggestions on how to handle the rendered part of the child component?**

Comment: It is too complicated. I hope i will never found code like this. Did you think about pure css approach ?

Comment: I think that you should not make side effects for component and influence on it in different way than by props. This will be hard time for other people to debug this.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I thought about solving it with vanilla JS+HTML+CSS, but it seems to be more complicated and is very hard to maintain. Do you familiar with a pure CSS solution?

Comment: @Robert What do you mean by "influence on it in different way than by props"? Can you give an example to change the text in every child element without knowing what components will be used?

Comment: eg. Some find bug in SomeCompoent so it will try to debug. So go to "SomeCompnent" check jsx and there is no any mark. No problem when there is one level of parent compoentn with provides highlight. But if there will many nested compoents and some component on top changes its html then it can be confusing.

Comment: try to change children: child.props.children,  to: children: [child]

Comment: HighlightText compoent should be ContextProvider. Then nested childs can check should they be higlighted. And then you can create some hook that check in context and make your transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to solve this problem using [`React.Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Not exactly as I expected, but I think it's even a better approach, because now I can decide what text to highlight.

It's similar to i18n and themes techniques in React. `React.Context` is best approach for these kind of text manipulations.